# Finding complementary of a collection in Macaulay2

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, macaulay2

Having a collection A of sets of the same cardinality t,  I am trying to find all elements in 2^[n]\A of cardinality t. Is it possible to do so in Macaulay2? If so, which packages are required?
How can one do it using ideal language?